# Why is an object possibly undefined after a *ngIf check in Angular 14?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We have an object that is defined by an interface, where the `category` and its `name` is optional:

```
export interface Product {
  category?: {
    name?: string,
  }
}
```

Now we want to render an element only if both the `category` and its `name` are set:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category.name }}</h1>
```

Unfortunately this throws an error:

> TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

```
<h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category.name }}</h1>`<br>
                                                       ~~~~
```

I can solve it by either one of these solutions:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category?.name }}</h1>
<h1 *ngIf="product.category && product.category.name">{{ product.category.name }}</h1>
```

My question is: Why is the first solution not working?

Comment: there are two separate TS evaluations here, one in *ngIf directive, and another in template interpolation, they're not connected, string interpolation does not _inherit_ check status from ngIf, so there is no _after_ ngif check

Comment: Thanks @traynor. That is also a good explanation in addition to Engam's answer. I guess this would also be a good separate answer on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first ngIf:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category.name }}</h1>
```

You are telling the template that product.category might be undefined and that it is ok for the ngIf to continue, by using the `?` character. But in the template `{{product.category.name}}` you are saying category definately do exist.

Because you have strict mode activated in your angular/typescript application, this throws an error.

When you write

```
 <h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category?.name }}</h1>
```

It works because you are telling javascript that product.category might not exist, and do nothing if it doesn't.

Additionally you can write:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product.category?.name">{{ product.category?.name ?? 'CATEGORY_OR_CATEGORYNAME_NAME_NOT_FOUND' }}</h1>
```

to have a fallback if category doesn't exist. `??` is called `nullish coalescing operator` if you want to reasearch more about it. It is very handy in javascript/typescript to use.

You can also write:

```
<h1 *ngIf="product && product.category">{{ product.category.name }}</h1>
```

if you only want to show the line if product.category exist. Because when printing `{{product.category.name}}` product.category must exist in this example, this doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. That explains it very well. I also like the last example because it's easy to read.